# Simple Java Hangman Assignment

Tags: java

I'm stuck on a java assignment for a class where we need to make a Hangman game but a REALLY BASIC one (It's an intro to Java class). Basically I have a word entered by someone and the other person has to guess the word but they dont see the word so it displays it like this for example (if the word is aardvark)

* * * * * * * *

Then the user inputs a letter and if its part of the word it then displays those letters, example:

Enter letter: a
a a * * * a * *

Enter letter: k
a a * * * a * k

Enter letter: r
a a r * * a r k

And so one...so yeah I've been stuck on this for a while and I REALLY need help
Thanks

P.S: This is an intro class so all I know so far are loops (for, while, do while etc), if, if/else, switch statements etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ass_2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  public static final Comparator<secretWord> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER;

    int attempts = 10;
    int wordLength;
    boolean solved;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("OK Guessing Player ... turn around, while your friend enters the word to guess!\n");
    System.out.println("Other Player ‐ Enter your word (letters only, no repeated letters and not case sensitive):");

    String secretWord = userInput.next();


    // 20 blank spaces WITH a for loop, we're smart!
    for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        System.out.print("\n");


        Scanner userLetter = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letter;

        System.out.print("Word to date: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        while (attempts <= 10 && attempts > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nAttempts left: " + attempts);
            System.out.print("Enter letter: ");

            attempts--;
        }

        System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
        System.out.println("Sorry you didn't find the mystery word!");
        System.out.println("It was \"" + secretWord + "\"");

}
```

}

Comment: What do you have so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I added the code to the original post

Comment: Ok, great. What are you stuck on?

Comment: Your for loop looks really weird... can you please make sure that you have correctly pasted the code.

Comment: Your `for` loop is not formatted properly.

Comment: You might want to rename your class to something that does not contain the word 'ass'. My professors never appreciated it :)

Comment: Alright code is fixed, ass stands for assignment :)
So I have no clue how to make it display the character entered by the user in the correct position (so it displays the * hiding the other letters but then if they entered the right letter if would display it, see example above :)

Comment: One solution is to store each tried character and when displaying the word, check if the next character to be displayed was tried. If yes, display the character, if not, display *.

Comment: @Jordan: try focusing on your immediate problem instead of the whole assignment. So the problem is to render the current word correctly. If the word is 'hello' and no letters are selected yet, it should be '*****'. If, let's say the letter 'l' is known, you want to display '**ll*; Try solving this problem first then worry about the rest of the complexity. In general, you should break down your problems into smaller manageable chunks then piece them together at the end.

Comment: @c_marker yeah, thats exactly what I want to figure out how to do! I know how to make it display the stars (just use the length of the string) but I can't seem to grasp how to make it display the letter if its correct, I tried using the indexOf(); but I can't figure it out

Comment: @Jordan: You can start by trying to write a method that takes a word and a letter. For each letter in the word, check whether the letter is equal to the one that was passed in. If not, print a '*', otherwise print the letter. Instead of modifying your current code, start from scratch for this... all the existing code might just confuse you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays ?

Comment: @Williwaw Cirse No, it says we're not allowed to use arrays

Answer (score 5):

Hey Jordan, your first attempt looks very good! You only need some more logic inside the while loop to read guesses and replace "*"s with correct guesses. And I would advise you to store the obfuscated word ("*****...") in a string also instead of just printing it out, will be handy later on..

Judging by your code you don't need any help on user input, your only problem is correct replacing of stars with right guesses, lets get to it:

```
String secret;
//read in secret string
String displaySecret;
//generate as many "*"s as secret is long and store them in displaySecret
```

Now the cool thing is this:

> ...no repeated letters...

which will make your assignment much easier! Look at the documentation of the String class provided by Williwaw. There you'll find two methods with which will lead to the solution:

- One method finds the first occurrence of a character inside a string and outputs its position. And since you don't accept duplicate letters, that'll also be the only occurrence.
- The other method can replace the character at a given position inside a string with another character.

I think from that you'll find the solution easily. Feel free to ask further questions in the comments!

**EDIT: Some more help**

```
String secret = "example-text";
String displaySecret = "";
for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++)
    displaySecret += "*";

char guess;
//read in a guess
int position = secret.indexOf(guess);
//now position contains the index of guess inside secret, or
//-1 if the guess was wrong

String newDisplaySecret = "";
for (int i = 0; i < secret.length(); i++)
    if (i == position)
        newDisplaySecret += secret.charAt(i); //newly guessed character
    else
        newDisplaySecret += displaySecret.charAt(i); //old state

displaySecret = new String(newDisplaySecret);
```

Damn I was sure there was some kind of setCharAt(int) method.. the loop does the job.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get the stars into the displaySecret string, I know how to display one star then just use a for loop for display it as many times as the length of the word, but thats it

Comment: @Jordan When do you display a '*' ? When both the character entered and those entered before aren't the character the "*" will take the place of. Also, I didn't even notice the "...no repeated letters..." >_< That's because of your example :p You still need only 2 String functions for the game without the "no repeated letters" limitation.

Comment: I understand the logic of it, but I honestly can't seem to get it coded lol So if the character entered by the user doesn't match a letter in the word then it displays a star and then if it does match it'll just not do anything and display the original letter, but it has to check each letter in the string one at a time, so by using a for loop

Comment: Ok, I tried your code, it does work (and I did change a few things) however for some reason it doubles the word, like if the word were "bob" in stars it would display \****** Thanks a lot by the way for all this help!

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, I put the System.out.println in the loop, which is why it doubled the length, so far so good! Now I'm going to try to tackle the rest of it!

Comment: Ok, so the code does work, however I tried to implement it into a while loop to monitor the amount of attempts and now when it gets into the for loop displaySecret, it keeps on duplcating whatever is stored in there, I think it has something to do with newDisplaySecret += secret.charAt(i);

Comment: @Jordan try to replace newDisplaySecret="" with newDisplaySecret=new String(""). Plus: Why don't you update the code in your question if you find some spare time.

Answer (score 3):

It's not so stupid, the aim is to make you more able to come up with original solutions.
Here, for example, you are working with Strings, so it would make sense to go on the javadoc and see [the String page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), to see if any function could come handy.
Next, comes the logic : you get a "String" input, then only get "char"s input and you have to compare a String with a char. So, the best way is to compare each "char" of your "String".
You can't use arrays ? Ok then, you can also use loops and two certain String functions (you already knows length(), which is one of the two), which will give the same result as going through a array to test each of its element.
The game end if no * is displayed or if there is no attempts left, so the player can try as long as neither of those conditions are true.

Comment: +1 I wanted +1 your comment but it's gone so now I'm +1ing your answer. Hope I didn't give too much assistance in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store a array of characters that is the same length as the secret word. Initialize the characters to `*` and when a match is found, using `[indexOf][1]`, reveal the found characters:

```
String secretWord = userInput.next();
int len = secretWord.length(); //Store the length which will be used to see if puzzle was solved.
char[] temp = new char[len]; //Store a temp array which will be displayed to the user
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) //initialize the array
{
    temp[i] = '*';
}
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print("Word to date: ");
while (attempts <= 10 && attempts > 0)
{
    System.out.println("\nAttempts left: " + attempts);
    System.out.print("Enter letter: ");
    String test = userInput.next();

    if(test.length() != 1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 character");
        continue;
    }

    char testChar = test.charAt(0);

    //Find matches
    int foundPos = -2;
    int foundCount = 0; //How many matches did we find
    while((foundPos = secretWord.indexOf(testChar, foundPos + 1)) != -1)
    {
        temp[foundPos] = testChar; //Update the temp array from * to the correct character
        foundCount++;
        len--; //Decrease overall counter
    }

    if(foundCount == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, didn't find any matches for " + test);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Found " + foundCount + " matches for " + test);
    }

    //Print 
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(temp[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    if(len == 0)
    {
        break; //Solved!
    }

    attempts--;
}

if(len == 0)
{
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Solved!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Sorry you didn't find the mystery word!");
    System.out.println("It was \"" + secretWord + "\"");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that without using arrays?

Comment: @jordan Everything is possible, Store a copy of the user-visible string. but Why???

Comment: Giving the answer is not helping a novice learn *how* to come up with an answer.

Comment: We're not allowed to use arrays for the assignment, which is pretty stupid

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a basic idea of the code upon which you can build:

```
public class HangMan {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter Secrect Word");
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
    String secrectStr = scn.next();
    StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder(secrectStr.length());
    for(int i=0;i<secrectStr.length();i++)
        b.append("*");
    char[] secrectStrCharArr=secrectStr.toCharArray(); 
    int charCnt=secrectStr.length();
    while(charCnt>=0){
        System.out.println("Secrect Word :"+b.toString());
        System.out.println("Guess a letter :");
        char guessChar = scn.next().toCharArray()[0];
        for(int i=0;i<secrectStrCharArr.length;i++){
            if(guessChar==secrectStrCharArr[i])
                b.setCharAt(i,guessChar);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to create HangMan Game

> package arr_game;

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangMan3 {
    public static char[] star;
        public static void main (String args[])
        {   
            char game[];
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random r = new Random();
            String[] arr = { "pakistan", "india", "jarmany", "america", "rashia", "iran", "iraq", "japan", "sudan", "canada"};

            String word = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
            int count = word.length();
            char[] CharArr=word.toCharArray(); 
            char[] star = word.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<star.length;i++)
        {
            star[i] = '*';
            System.out.print(star[i]);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf ("\nGuess a Letter:");
            char letter= input.next().charAt(0);

            for (int j=0;j<CharArr.length; j++)
            {
                if(letter == star[j])
                {
                    System.out.println("this word already exist");
                }
                else
        {
                    if(letter==CharArr[j])
                    {
                        star[j]=letter;
                        i--;
                        System.out.printf("CORRECT GUESS!\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(star);
            switch(i+0)
            {
                    case 1: System.err.printf("Strike 1\n");
                        break;
                    case 2: System.err.printf("Strike 2\n");
                        break;
                    case 3: System.err.printf("Strike 3\n");
                        System.err.printf("You're out!!! The word is Not_Matched\n");
                        break;
            }   

            System.out.printf("\n");
            if((new String(word)).equals(new String(star))) 
            {
                System.err.printf("Winner Winner, Chicken Dinner!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```